# Java 1.7 Update 45 - Unable to run unsigned jar

Tags: java, security, applet, unsigned, signed

I am able to run applets that have signed jar files on Internet Explorer with Java 1.7 Update 45.
I am however not able to run applets with unsigned jar files.
I tried clearing the cache.
I have also changed the security java control panel settings to Medium.
I still get the error `JarSigningException`.

Is there any way I can proceed here?
Are only signed jar files allowed? This looks like a major limitation.
Is there anyway I can tweak some settings to get unsigned applets to load?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sign the JAR. It's many times less expensive than any hand-rolled solution.

Comment: @LutzHorn  The one answer (not accepted) on that question is not a solution IMO.  It is not a solution because changing policy files is not something I'd recommend developers to do, let alone end users.  It is too fraught with peril.

Comment: At this point Java applets seem to be on the way out, Java 9 is dropping them entirely. Might be time to bite the bullet and use something like GWT/TeaVM to convert your Java into Javascript. You'd need to fix up the UI/Networking code, it doesn't seem that a seamless javascript polyfill will be available even for the most trivial applets in the near future: https://github.com/plasma-umass/doppio/issues/45

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way I can proceed here?

Sure.  Digitally sign the code with a certificate that links back to a trusted key chain.

> Are only signed jar files allowed?

It is progressing towards that, yes.

> Is there anyway I can tweak some settings to get unsigned applets to load?

On your own machine?  Probably for a little while longer, as Oracle continues to tighten the security along the lines you have discovered.

For the users?  No, nothing that is practical beyond 'educate your users as to the advantages of the digitally signed code', and to 'click OK when prompted'.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do if these are your applets is to sign them with a decent signing key.  (Or if the applets are solely for your own use, a self-signed certificate will do once you have imported it into your JVM's keystore as trusted.)

If these are applets supplied by someone else, either convince the supplier to sign them (with a good key), or stop using their applets.  Period.

The reason that Oracle are moving in this direction is that applets can do a variety of nasty things to your machine by exploiting security holes of various kinds.  Disabling unsigned applets helps protect the user from being a victim of malicious applets ... since the "bad guys" are unlikely to sign their code with a certificate that says who they are.

Comment: *"(Or if the applets are solely for your own use,.."* **..don't** make it an applet, just use a frame!  Applets are a PITA to develop & deploy (this is even before worrying about launching the applet in a security sand-box).

Comment: Yeah, I figured it wasn't.  Just wanted to add that caveat in there to high-light that 'applet' might be the wrong choice(1) for this deployment. 1) There are a vanishingly small number of use-cases that actually require a rich client GUI crammed into a web page.  The potential for 'continued sanity' decreases with each minute of such development.

Answer (score 0):

From appearances, Oracle really screwed up.  Not only did they break hundreds of thousands of man-hours worth of benign legacy applets... Having to digitally sign applets between local builds undermines new applet production.  They seriously need to give some thought to this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can always download and use an old version of Java (one that actually works...):
http://www.oldapps.com/java.php

I will never undestand why have the security slider in the Java settings if it does nothing...

After install, restart your browser.
It works like a charm for me.